# Create user dialogue not working in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I'm trying to create some users in SSMS without having to script them manually.

However, when I follow the [directions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/create-a-database-user?view=sql-server-2017) laid out in documentation, I don't get a dialogue. Rather, I get a script-to window, and an SQL template.

Why is SSMS giving me a template here, rather than showing the dialogue/wizard?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using an [Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-database/).

Currently this is an Azure SQL limitation. More information can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/adding-users-to-your-sql-azure-database/) on azure.microsoft.com or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins) on Microsoft docs.

When creating a new login with the following SSMS menu item on an Azure SQL database:

[image]

the following template script is generated:

[image]

while the following dialog window appears when using an on premise database:

[image]

Comment: You're right, I am using an azure SQL DB. Weird thing is, the dialog used to work, now it doesn't!